# Vectorizing nested-loop

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

For the last 3 hours I am trying to vectorize some piece of code. The idea is to loop over a matrix and compare all the values with the mean over the columns. If the values are larger, set them to 999.

```
comparevalues <- function(y){
  x <- apply(y,2, function(y) mean(y,na.rm=T))    
  for (j in 1:ncol(y)){
    for (i in 1:nrow(y)){
      if (!is.na(y[i,j]) & y[i,j] > x[j]) y[i,j] <- 999
    }
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Testing, e.g. with:

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1:3,NA,2.4,2.8,3.9,0,1,3,0,2,1.3,2,NA,7,3.9,2.4),6,3)
comparevalues(m1)
```

results in:

```
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]    1  999   1.3
[2,]    2    0   2.0
[3,]  999    1    NA
[4,]   NA  999 999.0
[5,]  999    0 999.0
[6,]  999  999   2.4
```

My question is:

1) Can this kind of structure be vectorized, and if so, how can it be done?

2) I am trying to use `apply` and similar functions in this context. Likely there are different ways to solve this, but for learning purpose, I'd appreciate if someone could address `apply` as well. However if there are better ways I'd like to know them too.

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Probably slower but more memory efficient solution would be `indx <- apply(m1, 2, function(x) x > mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) ; m1[indx] <- 999`

Comment: @DavidArenburg works perfectly fine, ty.

Comment: @akrun You are welcome to close even 50. SO will thank you and so do I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the `colMeans` to get the `mean` of the columns of 'm1', replicate it using `col(m1)`, check whether the 'm1' is greater than those value to get a logical matrix, extract the elements of 'm1' using that and assign it to 999.

```
m1[m1 >colMeans(m1, na.rm=TRUE)[col(m1)]] <- 999
m1
#     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
#[1,]    1  999   1.3
#[2,]    2    0   2.0
#[3,]  999    1    NA
#[4,]   NA  999 999.0
#[5,]  999    0 999.0
#[6,]  999  999   2.4
```

Comment: @akrun I get `NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments` when I try to use your code. Also maybe could you show me how to loop over a matrix using `apply` and referring to indices as well (alternative solution)?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Yes, there was a mixup when I was testing and copying it.

Comment: It works fine now. I'd give you credit already, but can you please refer to my last question in the comments (or the 2nd part of my main post)?

Comment: @EDC Looks like you got an answer from DavidArenburg for that.

Comment: ok but isn't that essentially the same as you did? It is perfectly fine, vectorization applied, correct result.
However my question was also in a broader context how to replace nested-for loops with the apply structure. Apply only loops over columns or rows, so I'd assume you need 2 x apply to replace a nested for loop? Some words with regard to this issue would be nice.

Comment: @EDC In your function, it seems to be looping unnecessarily as the dataset withiin the `apply` is  a vector.

Comment: that is correct but I had to refer to the column index somehow, and I did not know how to do this otherwise with apply.

Comment: @EDC Sorry, it's not clear.  What is the expected output?

Comment: I think I will open a new thread at some time where I explain exactly what my problem is. For now it's ok, thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: @EDC Thanks, it may be that you were looking for the column index, which can also be found using `max.col`